# Can I participate in showdown contest with friend?

Tags: application-development

Can I write an application, together with my friend? If I develop application with my friend, can I get T-shirt for me and my friend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can write the application with your friend, as you can see in the [Showdown contest rules](http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/rules/):

> [A]ll submissions must be new open source applications, created either
>   as an individual (the Participant) or in a team.

But i don't think that you'll get 2 T-shirts.

Comment: We have decided, once written, "Every submitted app also gets an Ubuntu T-Shirt!", we can write two applications so as not to offend each other? We are participating for fun :)